# Individual elements in a std::vector [C++]

Tags: c++, vector

What's the best way to select individual elements from a C++ std::vector?
I'm used to C-style arrays and this is the first time I'm using vectors.

I'm looking for something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> myvector;

astring = myvector[1];
bstring = myvector[3];
cstring = myvector[10];
```

And so on.

Comment: How many elements do you expect default-constructed `std::vector<std::string>` to have? Please don't rush in here if you didn't read the documentation.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a more complete example.
The vector in this case of course is empty. In the code I'm writing it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to access elements in a `std::vector`:

- `myVector[3]` - access the 4th element (0-indexed).
- `myVector.at(3)` - access the 4th element with bounds checking. Throws an exception if the index is not less than the number of elements.
- iterating over all elements with the standard algorithms: [`std::find(std::begin(myVector), std::end(myVector), 10)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Personally I've never found a use for `at()`, since I keep track of the index that I'm using anyway. I rarely just take a number from somewhere and stick it into `[]`.

But be aware that accessing an index not less than the number of elements using `[]` is *Undefined Behaviour* (if the `vector` has 4 elements, you access them with `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`). You are expected to be sure it is safe yourself. So in your example, this would be illegal, since you don't put anything into the `vector` first.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for the `best way`... The answer is: There is no general `best way`

The `best way` is not always the same. It really depends on what your code is doing.

The `best way` also depends on what you want to achieve, e.g. best performance, best code maintainability, best code readability and so on.

The `best way` is also based on a personal view.

So just to repeat the answer: There is no general `best way`

Other answers mentions a number of different posibilities. I'll add one more.

```
// To iterate over all elements in a vector you can do
for (auto& e : someVector)
{
    // Do something with e, e.g. print it
    cout << e;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three general ways to access elements of a vector.

The first one is similar to accessing elements of an array using the subscript operator [].

For example

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "Hello", "World" };

std::cout << v[0] << ' ' << v[1] << std::endl;
```

The second one is to use iterators similar to using pointers. For example

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "Hello", "World" };

auto it = v.begin();

std::cout << *it << ' ' << *( it + 1 ) << std::endl;
```

The third one is to use member function `at` that checks the boundaries of a  vector and throws an exception when an attempt is made to access memory beyond the vector

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "Hello", "World" };

std::cout << v.at( 0 ) << ' ' << v.at( 1 ) << std::endl;
```

Also there are methods to acess the first and the last elements of a vector

for example

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "Hello", "World" };

std::cout << v.front() << ' ' << v.back() << std::endl;
```

To access sequentially all elements of a vector you can use three kinds of loops.

For example

```
std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) std::cout << v[i] << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it ) std::cout << *it << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `operator[]` as you do with arrays. If you want boundary checking use `at()`.

Comment: @D.Porzio it would be if you inserted at least 11 elements into the vector before doing those accesses

Comment: @D.Porzio *Only* if the vector have been populated with at least 11 elements.

Answer (score 0):

That is generally how you access vectors, they were made to be similar to arrays using the indexing operator.

However, once you when you declare a vector like you do, without passing any arguments to [the constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) the vector is *empty*, which means that any indexing will be out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

If you want to specify an initial size, you could pass an argument to the constructor:

```
std::vector<std::string> myvector(11);  // Creates a vector of 11 elements
```

If you never will change the size of the vector, if the size is fixed at the time of compilation using a compile-time constant, then you should probably be suing [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
std::array<std::string, 11> myarray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access (i.e. select some element) a `std::vector` similar to C-style arrays i.e. by using indexes. Similar to arrays, no bound checking is performed in case of `std::vector` as well when you access some element which is not present. For example, you have inserted 10 elements in vector `v` but accessing 200th element using `v[200]` - but it could result undefined behavior, so be careful.